# How can I use a custom Python linter for a specific project with flycheck?

Tags: python, flycheck

I'd like to use [twistedchecker](https://github.com/twisted/twistedchecker) when working on the [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com) project.

Twisted has somewhat unusual [coding standards](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/development/policy/coding-standard.html) that aren't mutually compatible with PEP 8 (e.g. a mandatory three line gap between top-level definitions) so I would like the pylint checkers to be disabled and run only the twistedchecker and pyflakes checkers.

I've tried setting `flycheck-python-pylint-executable` to "twistedchecker" in my `.dir-locals.el` file, but that does not seem to change the output. (I have confirmed that it is set correctly).

I suspect that the answer is that I should write my own flycheck checker. There are [plenty of examples](http://www.flycheck.org/extensions.html) of how to do this, so that should be OK. What I don't know is:

- is there an easier way?
- if not, how would I tell flycheck to use the twisted checker for files in `~/src/Twisted/`?

I have also posted this question to the [Twisted-Python mailing list](http://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2015-June/029572.html).

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, you must write your own `python-twisted` syntax checker [1]. There is no easier way—actually I think it's already pretty easy to write Flycheck checkers.  You don't even need to look at extensions for examples:  You can just look at the syntax checkers in Flycheck itself.

Flycheck provides [`flycheck-checker`](http://www.flycheck.org/manual/latest/Syntax-checkers.html#index-flycheck_002dchecker) to explicitly select a specific syntax checker for a buffer.  To use a specific syntax checker for all buffers in a project simply set `flycheck-checker` via directory variables.  In other words, add `src/Twisted/.dir-locals.el` with the following contents:

```
((python-mode
  (flycheck-checker . python-twisted)))
```

---

[1] I wonder how you got the idea that changing the Pylint executable to an entirely unrelated program could possibly work…

Comment: twistedchecker is based heavily on pylint, and has similarly formatted output